# How do I cut an irregular shape into two parts along a path?

Tags: java, android, geometry

I have a fairly complex geometry issue I need to solve and I was wondering if anyone could point me at resources to solve it.

I have an irregular shape consisting of vertical and horizontal likes. It's described by a series of x,y points going clockwise to form a path. The last point joins up to the first to form the shape's boundary. None of the lines ever cross each other. When I'm drawing the shape on screen I use a classic scanline algorithm along the Y axis to turn the shape into a series of rectangles which I fill in.

But now I want a user to be able to slice the shape into two parts by drawing a path from one point on the boundary across to another point on the boundary again using horizontal or vertical lines. In the diagram the user draws from 1 and ends up on 2 at which point the slice takes place.

So here are a few examples of the sorts of things I have to cut. The original shape is cut into parts A and B using the cut path shown in red that the user draws. Note there is no guarantee user will cut in the same clockwise direction as my areas (i.e. 1 and 2 below could be reversed) so I have to deal with that.

[image: Example shapes with paths]

The line will be entirely contained within the bounds shape and won't cross over itself. i.e. when I cut the shape with the path it will result in exactly 2 new shapes.

Thinking out aloud I think the pseudo code for this probably goes like this:

1. Describe a shape as a series of x, y points, numbered 0 to N. N joins to 0 to close the shape.
2. Allow user to draw a cut path which starts and ends somewhere on the shape's path. The UI prevents the user crossing over their own line or drawing outside of the shape.
3. Work out which line indices in the shape the cut path starts and ends with. The line index is described by points indices 0->1, 1->2, ... N-1->N, N->0
4. To ensure user's cut path runs in same direction as shape, reverse their path if:
   a) The end shape line index  < start shape line index
   b) OR shape end line index == shape start line index but end cut point is closer line index start point
5. Construct two lists of points. 
   a) lines >= end index and <= start index + Cut Path, trimming start / end lines at cut points
   b) Cut path + lines >= start and <= end index, trimming the start / end lines at the cut points
6. Create new areas from point lists.

I think this would probably work but obviously it would be easier if there were actual code out there which did this already!

Comment: This isn't detailed enough to really be an answer, but Java2D has some boolean shape operations you could look at - either to use directly, or look at the source to see how they do it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/complexshapes.html

Comment: I just tagged it android since I'm writing it for that:) More specifically I'm writing code for OpenGL ES so it has to be fairly efficient too, i.e. minimal object allocation to reduce GC. I'd probably have to adapt any code I used to use my existing code and reuse array lists and stuff to keep allocations down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of code out there that does the job already.

You'll actually need the cut path reversed for one of your two new shapes, and not reversed for the other. (If what you said about all the shapes being traversed clockwise is right.) I think the easiest way to see which way around you want to take that path for each shape is this: (1) from the UI interaction you will know where on the shape the cut path goes; (2a) start at one end of the cut path, walk around the shape clockwise until you hit the other end, then follow the cut path back to the first end, giving you one shape; (2b) now start at the original end, follow the cut path in the other direction, and walk clockwise around the shape until you get back to the original cut path endpoint, giving you the other shape.

Aside from that, your pseudocode looks OK to me.

Comment: yes you're right. Looks like one would have to be reversed so I may as well always produce a reverse array and selectively use it or the other depending on which half I'm doing.

Comment: If I answered your question, you might consider accepting my answer. If not, what remains that needs answering?

Comment: I was really after code which did this already and had the pseudo code fairly well thought but I added a +1 for spotting the issue with the reverse path stuff.